# msbuild package task fails to include assembly DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: msbuild, packaging, strongname

I have a visual studio 2010 solution building an mvc 3 site.  One of my class library projects references the assembly DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll.  When I compile locally and on the build server, the xml assembly shows up in the bin, but msbuild on the build server tries to package it up, this one assembly is missing from the package.  The only difference I can see is that DocumentFormat.OpenXml is strongly named.

Are there special steps to package and deploy an assembly reference that is strongly named?  Do I have to install it into the GAC or something?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possibly a bug in Visual Studio:  I edited the project file in notepad++ from this:

```
    <Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.0.5022.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
```

and stripped off the extra properties to just this:

```
<Reference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml">
```

And now it is publishing.  Now I'll go back and remove each property to see if a particular one was causing the problem or just all of them.

Comment: This fix stoppped working.  :-(  I need to look for another solution.  Right now I have a scheduled task that copies the assembly in that folder but that's a crude hack and not helpful for when we deploy to production.